# Cleaning data dynamically after looping through table and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Before I insert the results into the staging table, it needs to be 
cleaned of all white spaces and carriage returns. I can sadly not provide 
sample data because it is private company data. All tables have different 
columns of type NVARCHAR*

```
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @CNAME NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @COUNT INT

--Storing all the database names with schema id = dbo
SELECT [name]
INTO #TEMP
FROM LIST.sys.tables
WHERE [schema_id] = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')

SELECT TOP 1 @NAME = [name] FROM #TEMP

--Looping through all the tables
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP) > 0
BEGIN 

SELECT @CNAME += '[' + A.[Name] + '],'
FROM LIST.sys.columns A
JOIN LIST.sys.tables B
ON A.[object_id] = B.[object_id]
WHERE B.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@NAME)
AND B.[schema_id] = 1
AND A.[name] <> 'Inserted_Date'

SET @CNAME = LEFT(@CNAME, LEN(@CNAME) - 1)

SET @SQL = '
SELECT ' + @CNAME + '
INTO #TEMP2
FROM [LIST].[dbo].[' + @NAME + ']
EXCEPT
SELECT ' + @CNAME + '
FROM [LIST].[STG].[' + @NAME + ']

--Here the cleaning needs to happen(Clean all columns from each table 
dynamically)

INSERT INTO [LIST].[STG].[' + @NAME + '] (' + @CNAME + ', [Inserted_Date])
SELECT ' + @CNAME + ', GETDATE()
FROM #TEMP2
'

EXEC(@SQL)           
SET @CNAME = ''   
SELECT TOP 1 @NAME = [name] FROM #TEMP  
DELETE FROM #TEMP WHERE @NAME = [name]
END
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Build a different `@CNAME` that has the `LTRIM`, `RTRIM` and `REPLACE` function only on varchar columns and use it on the `SELECT INTO #TEMP2`.

Comment: Perfect Thanks!!!

Comment: "I can sadly not provide sample data because it is private company data." -- Sample data doesn't need to be actual or "real" data. You can always make up some "fake" or mock data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably replace

```
INSERT INTO [LIST].[STG].[' + @NAME + '] (' + @CNAME + ', [Inserted_Date])
SELECT ' + @CNAME + ', GETDATE()
FROM #TEMP2
```

with

```
INSERT INTO [LIST].[STG].[' + @NAME + '] (' + @CNAME + ', [Inserted_Date])
SELECT ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@CNAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), ' ','') + ', GETDATE()
FROM #TEMP2
```